# Rota parou de funcionar somente na versão release

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Tenho um software aqui na empresa, e ele funcionava perfeitamente. Porém, fiz uma pequena alteração de layout e na minha máquina funciona perfeitamente. Quando publico a aplicação, a rota (**/Configuracoes**) retorna erro 404, como se a rota não existisse.

Criei uma outra rota (**/Config**), com o mesmo conteúdo e ela não funciona também.

Alguma ideia do que pode estar causando isso?

Comment: E qual é a diferença entre os dois ambientes? em produção ele está publicado em um subdomínio ou diretório virtual?

Comment: Não há diferença, fora o ip de acesso. É um servidor na rede. Não faz sentido não abrir a rota, pelo menos não para mim...

Comment: Você pode garantir que não é uma exception sendo estourada e tá sendo feito redirect como "not found"?

Comment: Como faço para verificar isso? Não tenho como depurar em release...

Comment: Ele está publicado no IIS? Tem como compartilhar o Startup?

Comment: Consegui resolver. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui solucionar o problema da seguinte forma:

Voltei até um "commit" que funcionava no git , e fui "comitando"
um por um e publicando. Até que descobri o commit.

O que aconteceu foi que um desenvolvedor criou uma rotina que necessitava
de um arquivo. Esse arquivo, por acaso, existia no repositório, porém,
não era criado pelo C# quando compilada a solução. Isso causava uma exceção
que não era retornada devido às configurações do servidor.

Ao ajustar o sistema para criar o arquivo caso ele não existisse, resolveu o problema.